# BouncyCastle based implementation for PrivateBin API

Tags: c#, powershell, encryption, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I'm trying to use BouncyCastle in Powershell for sending a paste to PrivateBin API.
Result so far:

- Local Encryption + Decryption with BouncyCastle is working.
- Sending a Paste to different PrivateBin Instances is working
- Open the Paste in Browser + Decrypt Paste returned by API is not working

  - Website asks for Password (but none is defined)

Does anyone know how to use BouncyCastle with the right params for PrivateBin?

```
function SimpleEncrypt {
   Param(
       [string]$secretmessage,
       [byte[]]$key,
       [byte[]]$nonSecretPayload = $null
   )
   if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($secretmessage)) {
       throw "Secret message Required!"
   }
   $nonSecretPayload = [byte[]]::new($null) #force set $null
   $plainText = [system.Text.encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($secretmessage)
   $nonce = [byte[]]::new(16)
   $crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::new()
   $crypto.GetNonZeroBytes($nonce)
   $cipher = [Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.GcmBlockCipher]::new([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.AesEngine]::new())
   $parameters = [Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.AeadParameters]::new([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter]::new($key), 128, $nonce, $nonSecretPayload) #payload als byte!!!
   $cipher.Init($true, $parameters)
   $cipherText = [byte[]]::new($cipher.GetOutputSize($plainText.Length))
   $len = $cipher.ProcessBytes($plainText, 0, $plainText.Length, $cipherText, 0)
   $null = $cipher.DoFinal($cipherText, $len)
   $authtag = $cipher.GetMac() #auto appended using DoFinal()
   $combinedStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
   $binaryWriter = [System.IO.BinaryWriter]::new($combinedStream)
   #$binaryWriter.Write($nonSecretPayload)
   $binaryWriter.Write($nonce)
   $binaryWriter.Write($cipherText)
   $cipherText = $combinedStream.ToArray()
   return @{
       cipherText = [convert]::ToBase64String($cipherText)
       nonce = $nonce
       mactag = $authtag
       key = $kdfkey
   }
}

function SimpleDecrypt {
   Param(
       [string]$encryptedMessage,
       [byte[]]$key,
       [int]$nonSecretPayloadLength = 0
   )
   if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($encryptedMessage)) {
       throw "Secret message Required!"
   }
   $encbyteMessage = [byte[]][convert]::FromBase64String($encryptedMessage)
   $cipherStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($encbyteMessage)
   $cipherReader = [System.IO.BinaryReader]::new($cipherStream)
   $nonSecretPayload = $cipherReader.ReadBytes($nonSecretPayloadLength)
   $nonce = $cipherReader.ReadBytes(16)
   $cipher = [Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.GcmBlockCipher]::new([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.AesEngine]::new())
   $parameters = [Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.AeadParameters]::new([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter]::new($key), $MacBitSize, $nonce, $nonSecretPayload) #payload als byte!!!
   $cipher.Init($false, $parameters)
   $cipherText = $cipherReader.ReadBytes($encbyteMessage.Length - $nonSecretPayloadLength - $nonce.Length)
   $plainText = [byte[]]::new($cipher.GetOutputSize($cipherText.Length))
   $len = $cipher.ProcessBytes($cipherText, 0, $cipherText.Length, $plainText, 0)
   $null = $cipher.DoFinal($plainText, $len)
   return [system.Text.encoding]::UTF8.GetString($plainText)
}

function PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash {
   Param([string]$password, [byte[]]$salt, [int]$iterations, [int]$hashByteSize)
   $pdb = [Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators.Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator]::new([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha256Digest]::new())
   $pdb.init([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.PbeParametersGenerator]::Pkcs5PasswordToBytes($password.ToCharArray()), $salt, $iterations)
   $key = $pdb.GenerateDerivedMacParameters($hashByteSize * 8)
   return [byte[]]$key.GetKey()
}

#example
[byte[]]$salt = [byte[]]::new(8)
$crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::new()
$crypto.GetNonZeroBytes($salt)
$kdfsaltb64encoded = [convert]::ToBase64String($salt)
$kdfkeygen = [Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators.Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator]::new([Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha256Digest]::new())
$kdfkeygen.Init("", $salt, 100000)
$kdfkeygenderivedparams = ($kdfkeygen.GenerateDerivedParameters(128))
[byte[]]$kdfkey = $kdfkeygenderivedparams.getKey()
$kdfkeyb64encoded = [convert]::ToBase64String($kdfkey)
$enc = SimpleEncrypt -secretmessage "hallo welt" -key $kdfkey
$iv = $enc.nonce
$ivb64encoded = [convert]::ToBase64String($iv)
$dec = SimpleDecrypt -key $kdfkey -encryptedMessage $enc.cipherText
$ciphertext = $enc.cipherText

$postbody = @{
   v= "2"
   adata = @(@("$ivb64encoded","$kdfsaltb64encoded",100000,256,128,"aes","gcm","none"),"plaintext",0,0)
   ct = "$($ciphertext)"
   meta = @{
       expire = "1day"
   }
}
$body = $postbody | convertto-json | out-string
$uri = "https://cpaste.org"
$header = @{"X-Requested-With" = "JSONHttpRequest"}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "$($uri)" -Headers $header -Body $body
$response
```

My try for decrypting from URL:

```
$header = @{"X-Requested-With" = "JSONHttpRequest"}
$decrypturl = "https://cpaste.org/?29cce083dbb9b6d8#FU4BjDSip6yv4HEmAJYzEJgwaMNxyCLih17vE4auf6vJ"
$decdata = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $decrypturl -method get
$iv = [convert]::FromBase64String($decdata.adata[0][0])
$salt = [convert]::FromBase64String($decdata.adata[0][1])
$key = PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash -salt $salt -iterations 100000 -hashByteSize 16
SimpleDecrypt -key $key -encryptedMessage $decdata.ct

$ciphertexttag = [convert]::FromBase64String($decdata.ct)
```

And the corresponding error message:

```
..."DoFinal" mit 2 Argument(en):  "mac check in GCM failed"
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to use SimpleDecrypt?  I would assume your problem is formatting-related.  When copying the values back out of the web page, are you sure your data types are correct before trying to decrypt?  When you try to decrypt, are you throwing an exception or is it decrypting into an incorrect plaintext or does it return nothing?

Comment: you're right, sorry for missing that. I've edited the original post.

Comment: If you claim it works without reading it in from PasteBin/PrivateBin, then your problem must be related to the values being returned from REST.  Run a test side-by-side with a local version and a web version and compare objects.  I believe BouncyCastle is block-aligned so make sure any required padding is present, the data types are the what they should be, and that the values are all what they should be (when compared to the local-only (and working)) version.